# Android: Is it better to use Bundle or another class to save data?

Tags: java, android, save, restore

I'm wondering if it's better practice to use Bundle or make another class entirely to save data?

During a fragment change I can set it up so that onSaveInstanceState() saves information. Alternatively, I could store that information as a static variable in another class, then create a getter function in that class and use it to "restore" the variables state under onCreateView().

I would much prefer to use another class as I feel like I have more control over the management of my data, but I'm not sure if this would cause any issues or if this is bad practice as I haven't seen any mention of people doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The Bundle.  Why?  Because your app may be killed.  For example, the user may navigate away from your app to another.  At that time, your app may be killed for resources.  They may then try to return to your app via the recents menu.  If you saved it to the bundle, the bundle will have been saved.  If you wrote it to a static, that data is lost.

It is acceptable to pass the Bundle to a constructor of an external class to initialize itself from that state, and to pass off the saving of the state to that class as well.  In many ways thats the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it your way, you will still have to make use of at least one of data persistence methods. If you don't use the conventional methods, you will be wasting resources which is a bad practice. Kindly look into the following scenarios;

1. If you want to retain the state of an activity without using either onSavedInstanceState() or SharedPreferences, how would you have done it? If you write a class to do this, you are actually re inventing the wheel.
2. If you want to use database, how would you have done it?

So Bundle is just a container that envelopes data i.e object, string, int etc so it can be saved either temporarily or permanently.

You have controls over your data except you don't understand how these data persistence methods work.

Please note, a bundle is not a way of saving data but a way to containerise sets of data so it can be saved as one